# Display image from folder to crystal reports Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I wanted to display the Dynamic image based on employee code from the Shared drive

Path - //10.9.2.40/staff/photos/'"+ empcode+'" + .jpg

The empcode will changes based on session.

This is the path where all employees photo's are saved.

I want to display it from shared folder only I don't want to insert records in database.

If anyone can help

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See video of ***Add a dynamic graphic: Crystal Reports 2011*** at:
https://youtu.be/5VmQk_JXyIo